Enemy teleporting between across the y axis, when it's under me while I'm on a platform, it teleports up the platform
I don't know if it's something with the AI, the navmesh, or maybe a missing nav component but the enemy I made instantly teleports to me when I'm above it instead of simply going up the stairs. It is normal when we have the same value in position for the y axis but it starts teleporting up when the y axis changes.
I've tried redoing the navmesh, I've tried changing around the prefab values and I just cant figure out what to do.
I'll leave the code and the values of the enemy object inspector below.
{
private NavMeshAgent agent;
public LayerMask playerLayer;
private WaveSpawner waveSpawner;
public GameObject[] allEnemies;
public GameObject closestEnemy;

//variables
public float sightRange = 10f;
public float attackRange = 1f;
public float patrolRange = 3f;
bool inSightRange;

private void Start()
{
    waveSpawner = GetComponent<WaveSpawner>();
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

private void Update()
{
    allEnemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    closestEnemy = ClosestEnemy();

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 1, transform.position.z);

    NavMeshAgent agent = GetComponent("NavMeshAgent") as NavMeshAgent;
    NavMeshHit closestHit;
    if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(transform.position, out closestHit, 100f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
    {
        transform.position = closestHit.position;
        agent.enabled = true;
    }

    if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, sightRange, playerLayer))
    {
        Chase();
    }
    else
        inSightRange = false;

    if (!inSightRange && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, agent.destination) < patrolRange)
    {
        Patrolling();
    }
}

GameObject ClosestEnemy()
{
    GameObject closestHere = gameObject;
    float leastDistance = Mathf.Infinity;

    foreach (var enemy in allEnemies)
    {
        float distanceHere = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);
        if (distanceHere < leastDistance)
        {
            leastDistance = distanceHere;
            closestHere = enemy;
        }
    }

    return closestHere;
}
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(transform.position, sightRange);
}

void Patrolling()
{
    float searchZ = Random.Range(-sightRange, sightRange);
    float searchX = Random.Range(-sightRange, sightRange);
    agent.destination = new Vector3(transform.position.x + searchX, 1, transform.position.z + searchZ);
}

void Chase()
{

        agent.destination = (closestEnemy.transform.position);
        inSightRange = true;
}

}


Edit, after additional testing, I've discovered that it's the 3d physical object of the enemy that goes through the floor and not the enemy itself.

so every frame you're going to move the player to x,1,z and then test if its on the navmesh and move it t the nearest navmesh position? that seems a lot - add some debugging to your code watch what goes on - also i thought SetDestination was the correct way to send your object using the navmesh, not directly setting the property

SetDestination doesn't seem to exist in unity.
but I will try removing the constant x, 1, z

The problem was that I was constantly setting it to
x, 1, z 

in Update
